# Translation Matrix not working properly

Tags: opengl, c++, mathematics, matrix

[image]

Hello,
I get this result when i try to scale and then translate a vec4 in my shader.
I created a mat4x4 class on my own and some functions wich return some matrices for me, everything works, but not the translationfunction.

Currently, I use this Shader Codes:

```
GLchar* vertexShaderCode = {
"#version 330 core                              \n"
"layout(location=0) in vec3 position;           \n"
"uniform mat4 scale;                            \n"
"uniform mat4 translate;                        \n"
"out vec4 vertexColor;                          \n"
"void main()                                    \n"
"{                                              \n"
"   gl_Position = translate*scale*vec4(position,1.0); \n"
"   vertexColor = vec4(1.0f,0.5f,0.7f,1.0f);    \n"
"}                                              \n"

GLchar* fragmentShaderCode = {
"#version 330 core                              \n"
"in vec4 vertexColor;                           \n"
"out vec4 color;                                \n"
"void main()                                    \n"
"{                                              \n"
"   color = vertexColor;                        \n"
"}                                              \n"
```

The matrix setup looks like this:

```
program.use(true);
h3d::mat4x4 mat_scale,
            mat_translate;
mat_scale     = h3d::Math::scale(.5f, .5f, 0.f);
mat_translate = h3d::Math::translate(.5f, .5f, 0.0);

GLint location_scale       = program.Uniform.getLocation("scale");
GLint location_translation = program.Uniform.getLocation("translate");

program.use(true);  
glUniformMatrix4fv(location_scale,      1, GL_TRUE,mat_scale.getRowWiseValues());
glUniformMatrix4fv(location_translation,1, GL_TRUE,mat_translate.getRowWiseValues());
```

So basically, the h3d::Math::scale(X,Y,Z) returns:

- X,0,0,0
- 0,Y,0,0
- 0,0,Z,0
- 0,0,0,1

And h3d::Math::translate(X,Y,Z) returns this:

- 1,0,0,X
- 0,1,0,Y
- 0,0,1,Z
- 0,0,0,1

The vertices are normal:

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.f,
     1.0f, 1.0f, 0.f,
     1.0f,-1.0f, 0.f,
    -1.0f,-1.0f, 0.f,
};
```

What do I am doing wrong ? I really appreactiate your help ! 
All the other matrices are working (scale, rotate, perspective).

Comment: What do these return: mat_translate.getRowWiseValues() & mat_scale.getRowWiseValues() ?

Comment: What if you transpose your translation matrix?

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL uses column-major matrices, but as I understand from your code you pass row-major matrices. So in GLSL scale[0] is the first column of scale matrix.